# Cannot read property 'addControl' of null

Tags: angular, nested-forms

Nested form, trying to add one form inside other but getting error 'Cannot read property 'addControl' of null'. FormGroupDirective not returning parent 'form' it seems. Trying to apply Sub-Forms approach for nesting.

```
    <p>
      sub-forms-approach works!
    </p>
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <!--<input formControlName="name">-->
      <app-sub-forms-approach-child-one></app-sub-forms-approach-child-one>

    </form>  
    state: {{form.status}}
    data:  {{ form.value | json}}
```

Parent Component

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from 
    '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-sub-forms-approach',
      templateUrl: './sub-forms-approach.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sub-forms-approach.component.css']
    })
    export class SubFormsApproachComponent implements OnInit {
    form= new FormGroup({

        });
      constructor() { 
      }
      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

Child Form HTML

sub-forms-approach-child-one works!

```
    <div formGroupName='address'>
      <input formControlName="pin">
      <input formControlName="street">
    </div>
```

Child Form Component

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ControlContainer, FormGroupDirective, FormControl, FormGroup} 
     from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-sub-forms-approach-child-one',
      templateUrl: './sub-forms-approach-child-one.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sub-forms-approach-child-one.component.css'],
      viewProviders: [
        {provide: ControlContainer,
          useExisting: FormGroupDirective 
        }
      ]
    })
    export class SubFormsApproachChildOneComponent implements OnInit {
      form;
      constructor(parent: FormGroupDirective) { 
        this.form = parent.form;
        console.log(parent.form);
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.form.addControl('address', new FormGroup({
          pin: new FormControl(),
          street: new FormControl()
        }))
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get `FormGroupDirective.form` in constructor because `@Input form` property  is not  initialized yet. Angular firstly instantiates component classes during node creation and only after that initializes input properties.

So move your code to `ngOnInit` hook:

```
constructor(private parent: FormGroupDirective) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.parent.form;
  this.form.addControl('address', new FormGroup({
    pin: new FormControl(),
    street: new FormControl()
  }))
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/bhEJxqHRJp31CpsfpXLQ)**

Comment: How would you change the validation on the child form from the parent form?  I tried using ngAfterViewInit in the parent when the child controls have been added, but the invocation of setValidators on one of the child form fields doesn't change the validation.

Comment: Getting, Cannot read property 'addControl' of null in Jasmine Unit test. Please help..

Answer (score 6):

The same error appeared to me when using the input property `formControlName="mainForm"` without a wrapping form group

Comment: you can use [formControl]="mainForm" if you are using mainForm as formControl

Answer (score 0):

alluded to in other comments, posts here...
I had a double typo...

FormGroup should be formGroup   (lower case camel)
and it needs to be in square brackets because it points to a variable

This was causing the error

```
FormGroup="myFormGroup"
```

This corrected the error

```
[formGroup]="myFormGroup"
```